# Google Maps Not Working in Release

Tags: android, google-maps

I have seen several questions about this on stackoverflow, I have gone through them and tried to understand them but it's either not very clear or I am doing something wrong.

I have generated my API keys in my google console, Key Restrictions has been set to **None** so I do NOT need to specify my App ID or SHA1 certificate fingerprint as some of those posts I've read have implied.

However my maps only show in debug and not in release, I have tried in my emulator and on phone with different android versions, I have checked my permissions now I do not know what to do.

I would like clear steps on how to get my maps working in my release version.
There are already questions like this but like I said I have gone through them and the solutions either did not work for me or were dated and not clear enough.

Comment: Its easy . Read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup .Click `RELEASE CERTIFICATE` TAB

Comment: I have already done that and everything was displayed to me.

Comment: From what I understand that command is just to display, what am I expected to do with that information? Like I set I have restrictions set to None for my API key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay so I'm new to google maps, apparently there were 2 google_maps_api.xml files, one for debug and one for release.

I noticed the one for release did not have an API key assigned so I just copied my existing key over there and now it works just fine.

Comment: Thank for sharing.Thanks a lot.